# How can I limit a Firefox profile to a single domain?

Tags: firefox, browser

I'm running a GNOME/Wayland desktop. With other browsers (GNOME Web, Chromium) I can open so-called app instances. These typically:

1. open at a preset URL
2. are limited to a single tab
3. have reduced/no chrome
4. **cannot browse to any other domain/subdomain**

   1. and, if I click on **a link to a different (sub)domain, it opens in the default browser instance** (whatever that happens to be)

How can I achieve features 4. and 4.1. with Firefox? (The rest are unimportant to me.) If a plugin is required it should have an FSF-approved license, but I'm hoping there's a setting buried somewhere.

Comment: Use acl proxy or netfilter rules.

Comment: your solution might be here https://askubuntu.com/q/487936/93232

Comment: Also see this bug report on mozilla.org https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1283670 it won't be implemented soon. Though someone developed a specific app for that on github: https://github.com/precz/wpaana

Answer (score 1):

According to [this feature request](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1283670) on Mozilla.org it seems that it will not be implemented.
Also someone mention on this request that he developed a XUL application able to emulate such behaviour only on Linux:

[wpaana Web page as an native application.](https://github.com/precz/wpaana)

Comment: Try it you Will see Last update 3 months ago my bet is that it could works

Comment: " Status: RESOLVED WONTFIX" is a guarantee that a feature request won't be implemented?